# Java: How To Grab Each nth Lines From a String

Tags: java, string, newline, lines

I'm wondering how I could grab each nth lines from a String, say each 100, with the lines in the String being seperated with a '\n'.

This is probably a simple thing to do but I really can't think of how to do it, so does anybody have a solution?

Thanks much,
Alex.

**UPDATE:**
Sorry I didn't explain my question very well.

Basically, imagine there's a 350 line file. I want to grab the start and end of each 100 line chunk. Pretending each line is 10 characters long, I'd finish with a 2 seperate arrays (containing start and end indexes) like this:

> (Lines 0-100) 0-1000
>
> (Lines 100-200) 1000-2000
>
> (Lines 200-300) 2000-3000
>
> (Lines 300-350) 3000-3500

So then if I wanted to mess around with say the second set of 100 lines (100-200) I have the regions for them.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string into an array using `split()` and then just get the indexes you want, like so:

```
String[] strings = myString.split("\n");
int nth = 100;
for(int i = nth; i < strings.length; i + nth) {
    System.out.println(strings[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String lines[] = text.split(newLine);
```

Where `text` is string with your whole text.

Now to get `nth` line, do e.g.:

```
System.out.println(lines[nth - 1]); // Minus one, because arrays in Java are zero-indexed
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to create a `StringReader` from the string, wrap it in a `BufferedReader` and use that to read lines. Alternatively, you could just split on `\n` to get the lines, of course...

```
String[] allLines = text.split("\n");
List<String> selectedLines = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < allLines.length; i += 100)
{
    selectedLines.add(allLines[i]);
}
```

This is simpler code than using a `BufferedReader`, but it does mean having the complete split string in memory (as well as the original, at least temporarily, of course). It's also less flexible in terms of being adapted to reading lines from other sources such as a file. But if it's all you need, it's pretty straightforward :)

EDIT: If the start indexes are needed too, it becomes *slightly* more complicated... but not too bad. You probably want to encapsulate the "start and line" in a single class, but for the sake of brevity:

```
String[] allLines = text.split("\n");
List<String> selectedLines = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Integer> selectedIndexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < allLines.length; i++)
{
    if (i % 100 == 0)
    {
        selectedLines.add(allLines[i]);
        selectedIndexes.add(index);
    }
    index += allLines[i].length + 1; // Add 1 for the trailing "\n"
}
```

Of course given the start index and the line, you can get the end index just by adding the line length :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't put this in the question, but would it be possible to get the start index and end index of each 100 lines?

Comment: @AlexPriceAp: Sure - but where do you want them? Will put them in separate ArrayLists for the moment...

Comment: A seperate ArrayList is fine. The reason I want the start and end is so I can use them as boundaries for my SyntaxHighlighter I'm developing, so I can highlight every 100 (for the moment) lines, as I'm developing for mobile devices and it can be slow with big files!

Comment: @Alex: Done - but I've only included the start index, as you can get the end index just by adding on the length.

Comment: Sorry if I've wasted your time, I explained my intentions wrong, added the update to the question.

Comment: @AlexPriceAP: Just use the list of start indexes then - you don't need the end index, as the end of the next chunk is always the start of the previous one.

Comment: Ah I see. Although I tested it and I seem to be getting the start and end of each line, not each 100 line chunks?

Comment: @AlexPriceAP: You shouldn't - because we're only adding to `selectedIndexes` on every 100th line. Are you sure your code is the same as mine?